# line_profiler: Unresolved reference 'profile' in PyCharm and IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, line-profiler

When using [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) PyCharm throws `Unresolved reference 'profile'`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning by the IDE. You can run line_profiler like normal.

I don't know why the error appears, but as you are unlikely to keep line_profiler in production it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share a code example? In the context menu of the error, there is an option to ignore the issue.

Comment: Will do! :) 
Thanks for the tip on how to ignore the issue. Won't it also potentially ignore relevant errors of the same kind then?